# Calling other *Async methods in custom stream class

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream, async-await

I have a class that derives from Stream and in its read/write, I need to hit a database. I wanted to use the *Async methods of SqlData objects but then of course it wants me to change the signature of the Read to have async modifier to something like this (I think):

```
public async override Task <int> Read( byte[] buffer, int offset, int count )
```

And that doesn't match the actual signature so I get an compile error message stating that. Any idea how I could pull off using *Async inside this stream or should I just leave it synchronous?

I also used Stephen Toub's AsyncLazy from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/15/asynclazyt/

My class is enabling streaming of data to and from a VarBinary(max) field in SQL Server with most ideas from http://www.syntaxwarriors.com/2013/stream-varbinary-data-to-and-from-mssql-using-csharp/.

Here are the interesting bits in the code (with the async bits commented out):

```
public class BinaryDataStream<T> : Stream
{
    /* Async */Lazy<SqlDataReader> lazyReader;
    SqlConnection connection;
    SqlCommand firstUpdate;
    SqlCommand otherUpdates;
    long position;

    public BinaryDataStream( DbContext context, string tableName, string keyName, string columnName, T keyValue )
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection( context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString );

        lazyReader = new /* Async */Lazy<SqlDataReader>( /* async */ () =>
        {
            using ( var cmd = new SqlCommand( $"SELECT TOP 1 [{columnName}] FROM [dbo].[{tableName}] WHERE [{keyName}] = @id", connection ) )
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@id", keyValue );
                /* await */ connection.Open/* Async */();

                var r = /* await */ cmd.ExecuteReader/* Async */( System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess | System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleResult | System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleRow | System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection );
                r.Read();

                return r;
            }
        } );

        firstUpdate = new SqlCommand( $"UPDATE [dbo].[{tableName}] SET [{columnName}] = @firstchunk WHERE [{keyName}] = @id", connection );
        firstUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@id", keyValue );
        firstUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@firstchunk", new byte[] { } );

        otherUpdates = new SqlCommand( $"UPDATE [dbo].[{tableName}] SET [{columnName}].WRITE( @chunk, NULL, @length ) WHERE [{keyName}] = @id", connection );
        otherUpdates.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@id", keyValue );
        otherUpdates.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@length", 0 );
        otherUpdates.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@chunk", new byte[] { } );
    }

    public /* async */ override /* Task< */int/* > */ Read( byte[] buffer, int offset, int count )
    {
        var reader = /* await */ lazyReader.Value;
        var bytesRead = reader.GetBytes( 0, position, buffer, offset, count );
        position += bytesRead;
        return (int)bytesRead;
    }

    public /* async */ override void Write( byte[] buffer, int offset, int count )
    {
        if ( count == 0 ) return;

        /* await */ connection.Open/* Async */();

        try
        {
            if ( firstUpdate != null )
            {
                firstUpdate.Parameters[ "@firstchunk" ].Value = buffer;
                /* await */ firstUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery/* Async */();
                firstUpdate = null;
            }
            else
            {

                var chunk = buffer;
                if ( count < buffer.Length )
                {
                    chunk = new byte[ count ];
                    Array.Copy( buffer, 0, chunk, 0, count );
                }

                otherUpdates.Parameters[ "@chunk" ].Value = chunk;
                otherUpdates.Parameters[ "@length" ].Value = count;
                /* await */ otherUpdates.ExecuteNonQuery/* Async */();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `Wait` or `Result` can tend to lead to deadlocks. Don't try to implement your synchronous variants by wrapping the async ones - go synchronous all the way down for the synchronous version. (And async all the way for async) See [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/)

Comment: Why do you want to use the async methods?

Comment: If you are asking why I want to use the *Async() methods of the db classes...just assumed I was 'supposed' to.  Any IO stuff, I thought the recommendation now is to use `await *Async()` whenever possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Stream` class has both synchronous and asynchronous versions of its methods.  Likewise, the database operations you're executing also expose both synchronous and asynchronous versions of their methods.  Override the synchronous methods with synchronous implementations and override the asynchronous methods with asynchronous implementations.

Comment: So, essentially, you are saying for me to use the async methods of db operations, the caller would have to be using the async methods of my Stream class?

Comment: That's why we have the `NotSupportedException` :)

Comment: @KaiBrummund There's no real reason to prohibit the use of the synchronous methods, if a given caller needs to perform the operations synchronously.  By exposing both you let the caller use whichever suits them.  You'd only need to throw if the underlying operations you were performing only supported one or the other, rather than both, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @Servy I've updated the question with the code I have exhibiting behavior that I have questions about.

Comment: @Terry Your program is incomplete, but by the (rather poor) name I assume you're writing to a normal file stream.  It doesn't have an implementation of `WriteAsync`, so even though your stream does, it's not the one doing the writing.  The reading that's being done from your stream is of course being done asynchronously.

Comment: @Servy I removed my comment with 'little' code in it.  I assume that is what your comment was referring to with incomplete/poor (hopefully).  So are you saying that since I have a FileStream in the mix (for reading), it doesn't implement *Async() methods, so CopyToAsync on the stream only uses the synchronous versions?

Comment: @Terry Yes, the snippet was poor because it's incomplete, but the comment was specifically calling out the variable names as being poor, because they don't clearly indicate what those variables are.  Also note that it's not appropriate to just keep editing new questions into your question.

Comment: @Servy I apologize.  Other than the Task.Run question, I thought they were just fine tuning,  trying to get to the overall answer of 'How to use async methods in derived Stream'.  Just trying to get the correct code to do that.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122214/discussion-between-terry-and-servy).